# Adding columns in Pandas depending on length of array?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

Given a sentence "Hello. I am writing a question", I want to split the sentence on punctuation and add each of the sub-sentences to an individual column in Pandas, such as:

```
dummy = ['Hello', 'I am writing a question']
pd.DataFrame(dummy).T
```

And I wish to do this iteratively, such as:

```
for subsentence in sentence:
    subsentence = re.split(r'[.|,|?|!]', str(subsentence))
    df['item'] = subsentence
```

This does however yield:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flattening:

```
sentence = ["Hello. I am writing a question", "Hello. I am writing a question"]

L = [x for subsentence in sentence for x in re.split(r'[.|,|?|!]', str(subsentence))]

df = pd.DataFrame({'item':L})
print (df)
                       item
0                     Hello
1   I am writing a question
2                     Hello
3   I am writing a question
```